# NPE(source2 is null) in RxJava Mockito Testing

Tags: android, junit, mockito, rx-java

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin, RxJava2, Retrofit and MVP pattern.

I am writing JUnit test code for Presenter.

```
@Mock
lateinit var mockRestService: RestService

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    mResPresenter = MainPresenter(
        view = mockView,
        restService = mockRestService
    )
}

@Test
fun test1() {
    val id = "id_01"
    val res = Res()

    // I am mocking in here:
    Mockito.`when`(mockRestService.updateRes(id, res)).thenReturn(Observable.just(res))
    Mockito.`when`(mockRestService.operateRes(id)).thenReturn(Observable.just(res))

    mResPresenter.operateRes(res)

    Mockito.verify(mockView).enableCancelButton(View.VISIBLE)
    Mockito.verify(mockView).onResOperating(res)
}
```

But NullPointerException occurred in my Presenter code.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: source2 is null

Below is my presenter code.

```
class MainPresenter(
    val view: MainContract.View,
    val restService: RestService
): MainContract.Presenter {
    override fun operateRes(vararg res: Res) {
        view.enableCancelButton(View.VISIBLE)

        disposable.add(
            Observable.fromIterable(res.toList())
                .concatMap { res ->
                    val updateRes = restService.updateRes(id, res)
                    val operateRes = restService.operateRes(id) // I am mocking it, but this is null... why?...

                    Observable.concat(updateRes, operateRes) // NPE occurred in here
                }
                .window(2)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    disposable.add(
                        it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe {
                                view.onResOperating(it)
                            }
                    )
                })
        )
    }
}
```

According to the Exception message, "operateRes" is null.
But I am mocking it.

What's the problem?...
How should I fix it?...

Comment: What line did the error occur on? Where do you define `restService`? How does `restService` relate to `mockRestService`?

Comment: I add comments on the code. restService is defined on the Presenter's constructor. restService is interface (Retrofit). So I am mocking it.

Comment: Where is `mResPresenter` instantiated? I don't see it in the code snippet. You have to make sure to pass the  `mockRestService` into your instance of `MainPresenter`.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie of Mockito. so I didn't know the important part. I added more details.

Comment: You need to trace how variables and fields are instantiated. If `restService` needs to be non-null, then you have to bind it somehow, usually during the construction of the object under test. I suggest you step back and find out how Mockito performs dependency injection, and binds mock objects.

Comment: I found that I was mocking with wrong value... it's my fault.